# Two lines of shell script

Tags: xcode, bash, build-process

I know nothing about shell scripting but something has come up and I need to be able to understand what two lines of code do so that I can modify a project I am working on

```
SDKROOT= make -C $TEMP_DIR -f $PROJECT_DIR/greg/Makefile VPATH=$PROJECT_DIR/greg || exit $?
$TEMP_DIR/greg -o $DERIVED_FILES_DIR/${INPUT_FILE_BASE}.m $INPUT_FILE_PATH
```

will you please explain what these two lines of code do... I know what the variables are and the path names but the rest of the syntax is confusing and foreign. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line:

```
SDKROOT= make -C $TEMP_DIR -f $PROJECT_DIR/greg/Makefile VPATH=$PROJECT_DIR/greg || exit $?
```

- `SDKROOT=` sets the environment variable `SDKROOT` to nothing for the execution of the `make` command.
- `make` is the build tool, and it's being run with the following options:

  - `-C $TEMP_DIR`: means run `make` in the directory `$TEMP_DIR`
  - `-f $PROJECT_DIR/greg/Makefile` specifies to `make` to use the Makefile in `$PROJECT_DIR/greg`
  - `VPATH=$PROJECT_DIR/greg` sets another variable, `VPATH` to `$PROJECT_DIR/greg`. `VPATH` specifies to `make` [a search path for prerequisits](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html#General-Search).
- `|| exit $?` means that if the `make` command fails the script should exit with the same error code as `make`, as `$?` means *the return code of the last run program/command*.

The second line:

```
$TEMP_DIR/greg -o $DERIVED_FILES_DIR/${INPUT_FILE_BASE}.m $INPUT_FILE_PATH
```

appears to be running the command `$TEMP_DIR/greg` with the option `-o $DERIVED_FILES_DIR/${INPUT_FILE_BASE}.m` and with some input from `$INPUT_FILE_PATH`. This looks like the program which may have been built from the previous line's `make` command, so it's hard to know exactly what it does.

#### EDIT

The SDKROOT is an environment variable used by XCode to say where the SDK it's using is installed. It will be a path like `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX"${HOST_VERSION}".sdk/` for instance. The value should be setup somewhere in XCode I imagine (I don't used xcode so can't be more helpful than that.). By doing `SDKROOT=` at the beginning of the command the value of `SDKROOT` will be nothing/blank. The reason for this is that the code being compiled will use resources which exist in the `SDKROOT`, rather than local ones; such resources may be classes, config or libraries for example.

Comment: Thank you very much... everything you said makes perfect sense. The first line is now much clearer and I will research the program options  so that I can understand the second line. The program is a recursive descent parser generator and the input file is a parsing expression grammar from which the generator generates code. After your explanation I'm pretty sure its saying to put the output in the derived files directory and that the input is the input files path

Comment: can you perhaps explain more about the SDKROOT variable and what its being set to?

Comment: @MattZera I've edited the answer to hopefully explain more about `SDKROOT`